# How to get old log details in log file?

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, log4j, struts

I am getting just one log file .and the past logs get deleted.
I want the past log files as backup.
It should not replace the old content but keep the old in separate file.
Following is my log4j.properties file

```
# Log4j configuration file.
 log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, A1
 # Available levels are DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL

 #
 # A1 is a ConsoleAppender 
 #

log4j.appender.A1 = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.File = C:/LogInfo/logfile.log
log4j.appender.A1.MaxFileSize = 100MB
log4j.appender.A1.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.A1.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern = [%d] %C %M %L - %m%n
log4j.appender.A1.Threshold = DEBUG

 #
 # A2 is a DailyRollingFileAppender
 #
 log4j.appender.A2=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.A2.file=C:/LogInfo/logfile.log
 log4j.appender.A2.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
 log4j.appender.A2.append=true
 log4j.appender.A2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.A2.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %C %M %L - %m%n

 # 
 #
 # A3 is a RollingFileAppender - Should be used in production only
 #   
 log4j.appender.A3=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.A3.file=C:/LogInfo/logfile.log
 log4j.appender.A3.append=true
 log4j.appender.A3.MaxBackupIndex=5
 log4j.appender.A3.MaxFileSize=10MB
 log4j.appender.A3.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.A3.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %C %M %L - %m%n
```

Comment: what's the problem that you are facing. This configuration will keep backup of files. May be your file is getting deleted as you rerun or redeploy your program.

Comment: I am getting just one file that is the current one ..There are no other files

Comment: those will get created once current is full. e.g after 10 mb or after a day as per log4j.appender.A1.MaxFileSize or FileAppender type.

Comment: My old log file got deleted after 10 mb.

Comment: I'm guessing ... but try deleting the whitespace around the `=`

Comment: You all appenders are hitting same file..

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which appender you are using - looks like probably A2 or A3.
In that case you need to increase the value of MaxBackupIndex - for A3, it is set to 5 meaning upto 5 backup files will be kept. For A2 this property is not defined so it will use the default value of 1 which keeps upto 1 backup file.

You should set these to higher values - say 1000, this would keep upto 1000 backup files each of maximum size 10MB(defined for A3).

```
log4j.appender.A2.MaxBackupIndex=1000
log4j.appender.A3.MaxBackupIndex=1000
```

Edit: Sorry, dint read the first line. Looks like you are using A1 appender and it will keep upto 10 files of 100MB each. You can increase these values to keep more older logs.

Comment: I have incraesed file size to 2000mb .It writes the log till 2000mb and after that the file becomes of 0kb and it starts witing again.It creates new file after 2000mb.I am not getting backup of files.

Comment: Try also log4j.appender.A1.append=true